# How to get messages from the RabbitMQ que and send it to users mobile using twillio API

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

I am a new learner and trying RabbitMQ with Laravel. I am using https://github.com/bschmitt/laravel-amqp this package. I am able to send the message to the queue
using `Amqp::publish('test.que', $message , ['queue' => 'test-que']);`  But now I want to fetch the messages from the queue and send the messages to user phone.

```
Amqp::consume('anish-que', function ($message, $resolver) {

    var_dump($message->body);

    $resolver->acknowledge($message);

    $resolver->stopWhenProcessed();

 });
```

The above code is used to access but how do I get all messages in an array so that I can loop and send all the messages to the users or what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Each message received from RabbitMQ will be proxy as one SMS ?

Comment: it could be but I want to get all the messages from the queue and store somewhere so that I can send the message to users. do you know any other way?

Comment: Why not simply persist on db right avec your var_dump ?

Comment: How do I do that? I am very beginner at this please help

Comment: when `Amqp::publish` is called it dispatch a call to RabbitMQ. Then it proxied to all `Amqp::consume` attached to the queue. Closure is runned for each received message. and will still continue to consume next one until you return false on your closure. Simply use Eloquant model on it to persist somewhere locally.

Comment: can you provide a simple code snippet for this please?